# Why doesn't my Python interpreter show type of data?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-typing, typechecking

[image: screenshot of the error]
When I move my mouse pointer on the variable `sum`, why doesn't the Python interpreter show me the data type in VS Code?
And also I don't know this problem is for VS Code or Python interpreter.

I uninstalled python extension and pylint and installed them again.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Since the question is about a vscode-warning I think this use of an image is OK

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, so this function will accept and return differing datatypes. You also give no type hints or generics typing. So, VS Code can't show datatypes, because you don't specify any datatypes anywhere.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @MatBailie the question is not about the return type of the function, but about the type of the variable that is initialized with the return value of the function, which is not the same thing. The typechecker in this case has analyzed what the function will return for the specific known input values.

Comment: `(variable) sum: Literal[35]` Isn't it exactly the type of data you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

**It does show the data-type**, look at the last line, the datatype here is `Literal[35]`.

You were probably expecting something like `int`, so why doesn't it show int? Your function-definition looks like this: `def sum_number(num1, num2):`. There is no explicit type-annotation, so the type-checker may infer it as `Any`. But in this case the type-checker is smart enough to understand that your specific invocation of the function will return the integer-value `35`. It does not generalize that to `int` since it uses the most specific type it can find.

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit annotations, pylance does not actively display the data type, for example, Defining a variable does not show `int`.

[image]

But it will determine and display the data type when it is called.

[image]

For your code, change it so that it displays the data type in either of the following forms

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first picture does show the data-type, it is `Literal[10]`. That is the most specific datatype that `var1` has. `Literal[10]` is a subset of `int`, so it is also true to say that `var1` is an `int`.

Comment: `var2` for `str` also shows `Literal`. https://imgur.com/BPWcQE4.png

Comment: So? Isn't that exactly correct? It is a feature of python-static-typing (or modern static typing in general) that you don't need to spell it out and the system will just infer the most specific type it can.

Comment: So Literal[10] just means that the value of a variable is the literal value 10, which is not a subset of the int type.Literal is just a type annotation for static type checking.

Comment: When interpreting types as sets `{10}` is a subset of `int`. Not all types need to have a runtime-representation as some kind of class-object.

Comment: Such a statement is not accurate or official. Like of course we know that 10 is int, it just doesn't show it.

Comment: it also doesn't show that 10 is `object`, `Number` or `int|str` even though all of these apply.

Comment: @JialeDu "*Such a statement is not accurate or official.*": Which statement are you referring to? [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) is meant to represent subtypes of `str`, `int`and `Enum` and the likes since they are sometimes too broad. [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) (the type checker behind Pylance) is using it exactly as intended.